# How to decrypt image before load with Glide

Tags: java, android, image, encryption, android-glide

I'm new to glide and I have a very annoying problem. I would like to load encrypted image from url to a image view with glide , below code works good if the image is not encrypted ,but I would like to load encrypted images from url with glide.Is it possible? Images are in the format JPG. Code i am using now

```
Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
.load(URL)
.crossFade()
.fitCenter()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
.into(chat_image_outgoing)
```

How can I decrypt the image before I load in it? Can I use ImageEncoder? please help me with code how to solve this problem.

Glide Version:3.8.0

Comment: `Can I use ImageEncoder`. If the image is encrypted you would need a decrypter to begin with. Even a decoder would not do. That would be for encoded images.

Comment: Okey but how can I do? How can I make a decrypter with glide? please help

Comment: I think your image is encoded. Please find out how.

Comment: what do you mean? My image that i load from URL is encrypted and I will decrypt image with glide? Just now I can't to load the encrypted Image. How can I decrypt the image with glide? Can I use ImageDecoder?  Give me example how I can decrypt the Image.

Comment: Please tell the encryption type.

Comment: Just now I use AES to decrypt and encrypt Images. I decrypt from a file but I think I need to decrypt from byte? What I should do?

Comment: How you should decrypt depends on how you can give the result to glide or how you want to put the result in an imageview yourself. I do not know what you decided to do now.

Comment: You did tell nothing new. You only repeated yourself.

Comment: Yes  I want to put the result in an imageview

Answer (score 0):

I recently use two ways to decrypt, though neither is perfect.

## Method 1. Decrypt and load seperately

1. Decrypt the target image file and save the result into a temp cache folder.
   The folder can be hiden like `.hidecache/` if u like.
2. Use `Glide` to load image from cache folder.

Pros: Easy for coding.

Cons: Leaving a decrypted cache file.

## Method 2. Use `GlideModule` to decrypt when loading

1. Create your own `GlideModule`, `ModelLoader` and `DataFetcher`.
2. Inside the `DataFetcher`, use `FilterInputStream` to process/decrypt the InputStream ( just override the two `read()` methods)

Pros: No cache file if Glide cache type is set properly.

Cons: All `GlideModule` are registered in `AndroidManifest`, which makes it easier to found out how the image is decrypted.

## Conclusion

Keep this in mind:

As decrypted images will be shown on screen finally, everyone can use screenshot to get them.

Good luck :)